# What's the correct format of y3 signal

Tags: matlab, signals

I have written the following code:

```
freq=[261.626, 277.183, 293.665, 311.127, 329.628, 349.228, 369.994, 391.995,...
    415.305, 440.000, 466.164, 493.883, 523.251, 554.365,...
    587.330, 622.254, 659.255, 698.456, 739.989, 783.991, 830.609, 880.000,...
    932.328, 987.767];
freq_length=length(freq);

notes=['C4 ';'C#4';'D4 ';'D#4';'E4 ';'F4 ';'F#4';'G4 ';'G#4';'A4 ';'A#4';...
    'B4 ';'C5 ';'C#5';'D5 ';'D#5';'E5 ';'F5 ';'F#5';'G5 ';'G#5';'A5 ';'A#5';'B5 ']; 
notes_length=length(notes);

Duration=[1,1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,1/32,1/64];
DurationLength=length(Duration);
DurationName=['whole Note','halfNote','QuarterNote','EighthNote','SixteenthNote',...
'ThirtySecondNote','SixtyFourNote'];

increases=[0,1/2,3/4,9/8];
IncreasesLength=length(increases);
increasesName=['ZeroDots','OneDot','TwoDots','ThreeDots'];

%endeiktikh timh sampleRate
SampleRate=1/20000;

%typikh timh (se sec gia thn whole note)
TimeValue=1.6;

TimeNotesSize=int64(IncreasesLength)*int64(DurationLength);
TimeNotes=zeros(TimeNotesSize,1);

%Ypologismos TimeValue gia kathe Duration,increases
for i=1:DurationLength
    for j=1:IncreasesLength
        TimeNotes(j+IncreasesLength*(i-1))=Duration(i)*(1+increases(j))*TimeValue;
        %disp(j+IncreasesLength*(i-1));
    end
end

for i = 1:TimeNotesSize
    soundVector = zeros(notes_length,TimeNotesSize,int64(TimeNotes(i)/SampleRate));
end

for i = 1:1:notes_length % for every note
    for j=1:TimeNotesSize %for every note duration
        for k=0:SampleRate:TimeNotes(j) %for the SampleRate space
            soundVector(i,j,int64(k/SampleRate)+1)=sin(2*pi*freq(i)*k);
        end
    end
end

%spectogram
y1=sin(2*pi*freq(1)*(0:SampleRate:TimeValue));
y2=sin(2*pi*freq(1)*(0:SampleRate:TimeNotes(1)));
y3=soundVector(1,1,:);
window=hamming(512);
noverlap=256;
nfft=1024;
[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(y3,window,noverlap,nfft,Fs,'yaxis');
surf(T,F,10*log10(P),'edgecolor','none');
axis tight; 
view(0,90);
set(gca,'clim',[-80,-30]);
xlabel('Time (seconds)');
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)');
```

The main goal is given a music song, print the pentagram notes of this song. I can print the `y1` and `y2` signals, but not that of `y3`. The `y3` and `y2` signals must be the same.

The error that console returns is:

```
Error using welchparse>segment_info (line 188)
The length of the segments cannot be greater than the length of the input signal.

Error in welchparse (line 32)
[L,noverlap,win] = segment_info(M,win,noverlap);

Error in spectrogram (line 172)
[x,nx,~,~,~,win,~,~,noverlap,~,~,options] = welchparse(x,esttype,varargin{:});

Error in play_notes (line 57)
[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(y3,window,noverlap,nfft,Fs,'yaxis');
```

What isis it that I am doing wrong?

First error: >`[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(y2,window,noverlap,nfft,1/SampleRate,'yaxis');` instead of `[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(y3,window,noverlap,nfft,Fs,'yaxis');`

Second error:
`y3=soundVector(1,1,1:int64(TimeNotes(1)/SampleRate));` instead of `y3=soundVector(1,1,:);`

Comment: The code runs without problems MATLAB 2015b with Signal Processing Toolbox.

Comment: @user1391279 Thanks for the reply. I have Matlab R2016a. I have installed signal feature (signal processing toolbox as you say). So this is an internal bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why (:,:) is necessery but `[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(y3(:,:),window,noverlap,nfft,1/SampleRate,'yaxis');` works!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used `squeeze(y3)` to get the answer. `y3` is a 3-dimensional matrix (`size(y3)==[1 1 68001]`) in your problem - you would need to convert it to a  vector to use `spectrogram`. Your solution would also wor. Also I am not sure if it was constructed in the appropriate manner, as the second half of the signal is padded with zeros.